# Divisibility Problem from an Olympiad Book

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving

In a practice problem set of the Olumpiad book that I am solving, the following question has me stumped.
$$\text{Prove that }3(7^{200}+7^{202}+7^{204})+7(3^{200}+3^{204}) -210 \text{ is divisible by 10.}$$
My attempt is as follows

---

Using the Sum of GP formula
$$3\cdot7^{200}\Big(\frac{49^3-1}{49-1}\Big)+7\cdot3^{200}(\frac{81^2-1}{81-1}) -210 $$
Simplifying we get,
$$ 7353\cdot7^{200}+574\cdot3^{200}-210$$

Now the proof is equivalent to showing that
$$7353\cdot7^{200}+574\cdot3^{200} \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
Since both 7 and 3 are coprime to 10, by Euler's Theorem $3^4 \equiv 7^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$
So, we get
$$ 7353 + 574 \equiv 7 \mod 10 $$
**This is the problem**

---

Any insight or an alternate approach would be helpful.

Comment: It is $\equiv7\bmod10$.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?  Why would they subtract $210$?  (That would not change divisibility by $10$)

Comment: It is enough to look at the unit digit (or modulo $10$). For this, substitute $7^2$ and $3^2$ by $-1$.

Comment: Is there any chance you're missing a term of $3^{202}$ in the second parentheses?  Also the $-210$ term seems really peculiar as it obviously has no influence on divisibility by $10$.  By the way, I agree that for the problem as written, the result is congruent to $7$ (mod $10$).

Comment: I copied the question _as is_ from the book. Maybe there's a typo.

Comment: What's the name and author of the book?

Comment: $3 (7^{200} + 7^{202} + 7^{204}) + 7 (3^{200} + 3^{204}) - 3×7^{210}$ is divisible by $10$

Answer (score 3):

Much easier, noting that $7^2 = 49 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$ and $3^2 = 9 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$, and considering the effect of raising $-1$ to odd and even powers, you can almost immediately reduce the expression modulo $10$ to $3(1-1+1)+7(1+1) - 0 = 17 \equiv 7$.

You are correct, the question as stated is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's false -- at least as stated.

Easy way to check that is look at parity (mod 2).
$7^{200} + 7^{202} + 7^{204}$ is odd + odd + odd, so is odd.
$3^{200} + 3^{204}$ is odd + odd, so is even.
3 * odd is odd, 7 * even is even.  odd + even is odd, odd - 210 is odd.
So your overall result is odd, and thus not divisible by 10.

Answer (score 0):

As others have observed, the $-210$ does not serve any purpose. So I'll just work on evaluating the rest of the terms modulo $10$. All this work easily generalizes.

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}3(7^{200}+7^{202}+7^{204}) + 7(3^{200}+3^{204}) & \equiv & 3((-3)^{200}+(-3)^{202}+(-3)^{204}) \\ & & - 3(3^{200}+3^{204}) \pmod{10} \\ & \equiv & 3^{203} \pmod{10} \\ & \equiv & \big(3^4\big)^{50} \cdot 3^3 \pmod{10} \\ & \equiv & 3^3 \pmod{10} \qquad \ldots \:\: \text{since} \:\:3^4 \equiv 1\pmod{10} \\ & \equiv & 7\pmod{10}. \quad \blacksquare \end{eqnarray*} $$